# Generate shell flags and arguments inline

Tags: shell, docker-compose

I want to pass multiple files to docker-compose, which needs a `-f` flag for each file. Effectively I am looking for a way to generate this command:

`docker-compose -f file-a.yml -f file-b.yml -f file-c.yml -f docker-compose.yml up`

`-f file-*.yml` does not work, since it does not generate the mandatory `-f` flag

I'd like the argument generation to be inline but could not come up with the correct search terms to find a solution online.

Comment: `$(for f in file-*.yml ; do printf ' -f %s' "${f}" ; done)`? (But don’t use it unless you _know_ the files’ names contain no funny characters.)

Comment: @Biffen Exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: why not just extends into the docker-compose file ? eg: https://gist.github.com/pawndev/4bc04d9a140f613978d2b5eed3f82809

Comment: @ChristopheCoquelet Thanks! Didn't know this was possible. This opens new possibilities

Comment: @Biffen Why do you go for `printf` instead of `echo`? Are there any advantages to that?

Comment: @joschal Habit, mostly, but see also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo